# Get the value of array using c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I got an array

`string [] strings = new string[] {"1", "2", "2", "2", "1"};`

You can see the value of the array is just 1 and 2, just 2 values, you could say, and I want to get those value out...What I did is here, just a start:

```
string[] strings = new[] { "1", "2", "2", "2", "1"};
int[] ints = strings.Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();
```

I don't what is next...Anyone helps?

Comment: *I don't what is next?* What do you want to do with the extracted `int[]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may simply add a distinct to get the unique values:

```
int[] ints = strings.Select(x => int.Parse(x)).Distinct().ToArray();
```

Thus your array contains the elements `{1, 2}`

Comment: Nice,,Thanks a lot~~~

Answer (score 4):

You mean you just want an array `int[] {1, 2}`?

```
string[] strings = new[] { "1", "2", "2", "2", "1"};
int[] ints = strings.Select(int.Parse).Distinct().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Classic way:

```
        string[] strings = new[] { "1", "2", "2", "2", "1" };
        List<int> items = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < strings.Length; i++)
        {
            int item = int.Parse(strings[i]);

            if (!items.Contains(item))
                items.Add(item);
        }
```